# How To Populate a Dialogue in React Using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, dialog, material-ui, use-effect

I have need to display some information using Material UI dialogue. Calling handleOpen function inside the useEffect hook causes the dialogue to open by default when the page is open. Can someone help to show me how to populate the dialogue only when a button is clicked? Please note that the postId is passed as props from the parent component. Thanks in advance

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
 import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

 import { getSinglePost } from '../../store/actions/postActions'

 //MUI Components
 import { Dialog, DialogHeader, Button, DialogContent, DialogActions, Grid, Typography, IconButton} 
 from '@material-ui/core'
 import LaunchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Launch';


const PostDialog = ({postId}) => {
    const [ open, setOpen ] = useState(false)

    const post = useSelector(state => state.posts.post)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
       handleOpen()
    }, [])


const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen({ open: true })
    dispatch(getSinglePost(postId))
}

const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen({ open: false })
}

return (
    <div>
        <Button onClick={handleOpen}>
            <LaunchIcon fontSize="small" color="primary" />
        </Button>
        <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose} 
        fullWidth
        maxWidth="sm"
        >
            <DialogContent>
                <Grid container>
                    <Grid item sm={5}>
                        {/* <img src={userImage} width="150" /> */}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                    <Typography variant="h6">@{post.handle}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h6">{post.job_title}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">{post.long_description}</Typography>

                    </Grid>


                </Grid>
            </DialogContent>

        </Dialog>
        
      </div>
   )
 }


 export default PostDialog
```

Comment: remove useEffect you dont need it, you are already calling the function on the button click

Comment: So if the `useEffect` hook is opening the dialog when the component mounts, and the button opens *any other* time, and you don't want the dialog to open upon component mount, then simply remove the mounting `useEffect` React hook call.

Comment: For some reasons unknown to me, if I remove the useEffect hook, the action does not trigger immediately and so the dialogue is never populated with the data from the state

Comment: If you remove the `useEffect` hook then yes, the action will wait to be dispatched until you actually click the open button. The `post` data should then be populated (*I am assuming that is what the action does*).